# Get host IP from Vagrant and use it with Ansible

Tags: node.js, vagrant, ansible, ansible-facts

I playing around with vagrant to set up some droplets and deploy my nodejs server with ansible (I am using `DigitalOcean`). I have some parts in my js code where I need to set the **current IP** into the script. Problem is that I *can't* set the IP manually so I get a random IP via vagrant from `DO`. How can I "get" this IP and make use of it in my Ansible script? sure I just could do a `wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -` on the host itself or check it with `ip` but I guess it should also work to get this info from Vagrant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (specifically: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts), Ansible seems to have a pre-defined variable containing your networking information:

```
"ansible_eth0": {
    "active": true,
    "device": "eth0",
    "ipv4": {
        "address": "REDACTED",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
        "network": "REDACTED"
    },
    "ipv6": [
        {
            "address": "REDACTED",
            "prefix": "64",
            "scope": "link"
        }
    ],
    "macaddress": "REDACTED",
    "module": "e1000",
    "mtu": 1500,
    "type": "ether"
},
```

I can't remember which is the public interface on DigitalOcean, but you should be able to use `{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}` in your playbook.

Side note, you can use this command to list all "discovered" variables:

```
ansible hostname -m setup
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I "get" this IP and make use of it in my Ansible script?

Use [ipify_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ipify_facts_module.html):

```
- name: Get my public IP
  ipify_facts:

- debug: var=ipify_public_ip
```